# Three Quarters in Rugby

Tags: rules, rugby-union, rugby

I've got the idea of all the player positions in `Rugby`. Is there a position called `Three Quarters`, if I'm not mistaken?. Some used to mention it by that way, but I've got no idea what it really mean?

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Could you clarify whether you're interested in union, league or both?

Comment: Yes I'm interested hear about both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"There are four threequarters: two wingers and two centres. Right wing (2), right centre (3), left centre (4) and left wing (5). Typically these players work in pairs, with one winger and one centre occupying each side of the field."

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rugby_union_positions#Three-quarters

Essentially if you are already familiar with the centre and wing position you also know what threequarters means because it is just a combination of those positions

position 2,3,4,5 in the graphic below

https://i.stack.imgur.com/U2sK4.jpg

Comment: You know you're quoting an article on league there?